# Javascript WP Object Documentation?

Tags: javascript, media-library, documentation

I was working on implementing the media library within one of my plugins/themes. I found a nice tutorial (http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/) that showed me how to do this using the JS object 'wp'

I can't seem to find any documentation on this in the codex or when Googling. How does one learn this object and its methods?

Comment: See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26870 for the current documentation efforts.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'm curious how I see so many people using these objects without any documentation. Should I assume they went through the source like this person did and figured it out?

Comment: Either that, or they have written the core part. :)

Comment: This isn't "documentation" per se, but you can learn a lot from reading the source and observing how Wordpress itself leverages the Media Library JS.  See https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/media-editor.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp

It's a work in progress. Contribute if you can!

Comment: update (2021): ever since 2014, still work in progress.
no one contributed if he could

Answer (score 1):

Since there is still no real documentation in codex/developer docs, the only way is WordPress Trac:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk#src/js/_enqueues/wp

All components are at least commented and each file has a header with a description.